# ML Inequality and Complex Integrals

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I have a question about the ML-Inequalty and how it applies on complex integrals.

Getting this page from Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma  the denominator in the f(z) is $(z² + 1)²$. Using the absolute value with the triangular inequality we'll get $(z² +1)² \ge |z²| - 1 = r² - 1 $ where $ |z| = r $.

So, I'll get after some algebra this:

$
| 1 /(z² + 1)² | \le 1/(r² -1)²
$

So, here is the question : Do I always need to use the triangle inequality to get the highest upper bound for the $f(z)$ function ?

Just another thought :

If I have the function $f(z) = 1/(z² - 1)$ , why can't I use the :

$ M  = 1/(a² -1) $

Because from the triangular inequality I should get :

$
|z²-1| \le a² + 1
$
and
$
|z²-1| \ge a² - 1
$

After some algebra :

$ 1/|z² +1| \le 1/(a² + 1) \le 1/(a²-1) $

In some texts I saw people using the middle term.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, you don't "always have to use the triangle inequality". Any bound that is good enough will do, but the triangle inequality is a powerful tool and often useful.

For your particular question, it is correct that

$$|z^2-1| \le a^2+1$$

if $|z| \ge a (\ge 1)$ but this implies that

$$
\frac{1}{|z^2-1|} \ge \frac{1}{a^2+1}.
$$
Note the change in the direction of the inequality! Hence your estimate goes in the wrong direction. You want to bound $|f|$ from above, not from below.

On the other hand, a sharp estimate is rarely needed. It's often just as good to use a weaker estimate, such as
$$
\frac{1}{z^2-1} \le \frac{C}{a^2}
$$
for some constant $C$, or in "big-O" notation $\le O(a^{-2})$. In fact, it's a (fairly) easy exercise to show that if $p$ is a polynomial of degree, then $|p(z)| \le C|z|^n$ for some constant $C$ is $|z|$ is large enough, and this is just the kind of estimate you need for most basic applications of the residue theorem.

Comment: Wow man, I thought that I'd receive a mail when this question got a response. 

So , I'm sorry, I didn't say : thank you! =)